# Unable to read stdout from python with popen in lua

Tags: python, lua, stdout, popen

I am trying to read the stdout of a simple python script

```
    import time
    while True:
        print("test")
        time.sleep(1)
```

with the following lua code

```
    local p = assert(io.popen("/usr/bin/python test.py", "r"))
    if not p then
        print("error")
    end
    print("process: "..tostring(p))

    while p do
        local line = p:read("*l")
        if line then
            print("line: "..tostring(line))
        end
    end
```

This prints a process file identifier but no output.

Substituting `yes` as command shows that the lua code in itself should work. However no method of calling the python script (including shebang) will produce any output. Changing to `sys.stdout.write("test" + "\n")` doesn't make a difference either.

I tried it on two machines running archlinux and debian. The first one is running python 3.7.2 and lua 5.3.5.

Comment: Could you remove the while loop in the `python` script and try ?

Comment: Ok, that does produce output once.

Comment: It also works in a for loop.  Does this mean python buffers the prints until the while loop terminates?

Comment: Try, `sys.stdout.write("test" + "\n"); sys.stdout.flush()` :)

Comment: Cool, thanks! I was struggling for days with this thinking the problem was with love2d or lua. I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36131331/11055460) that shows some other ways.